changing the hounsfield unit for a specific organ
I have CT images and RT structure in dicom. I want to change the Hounsfield unit of the heart to a constant value like 100. I have been able to calculate and display the Hounsfield unit for the heart, but I cannot change the Hounsfield value to 100. Can you guide me?
import os
import pydicom
import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Directory containing CT images
ct_directory = r"D:\ct directory"

# Path to your RT Structure file
rt_struct_path = r"D:\RTS2.dcm"

# Load CT images
ct_files = [f for f in os.listdir(ct_directory) if f.endswith('.dcm')]
ct_images = [pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(ct_directory, f)) for f in ct_files]
ct_images.sort(key=lambda x: float(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))

# Load RT Structure
rt_struct = pydicom.dcmread(rt_struct_path)

# Identify the specific ROI number for the heart (adjust 'heart' if necessary based on your DICOM  files)
heart_roi_number = None
for roi in rt_struct.StructureSetROISequence:
    if 'heart' in roi.ROIName.lower():  # Adjust the condition based on the exact name
        heart_roi_number = roi.ROINumber
        break

if heart_roi_number is None:
    raise ValueError("Heart ROI not found")

# Loop through each CT slice and process contours to calculate Hounsfield Units
for img in ct_images:
    try:
        img.contour_points = []  # Ensure this attribute is reset for each image

        # Check if this slice contains the heart contour
        heart_contour_found = False
        for roi_contour in rt_struct.ROIContourSequence:
            if roi_contour.ReferencedROINumber == heart_roi_number:
                for contour in roi_contour.ContourSequence:
                    contour_data = np.array(contour.ContourData).reshape((-1, 3))

                    # Process each point in the contour
                    for point in contour_data:
                        z_value = point[2]

                        # Find the corresponding CT slice for this point
                        if abs(img.ImagePositionPatient[2] - z_value) < 1e-2:

                            # Correctly convert this point's (x, y) to pixel coordinates
                            x, y = point[:2]
                            col = np.round((x - img.ImagePositionPatient[0]) /    img.PixelSpacing[0]).astype(int)
                            row = np.round((y - img.ImagePositionPatient[1]) /  img.PixelSpacing[1]).astype(int)

                            img.contour_points.append((row, col))

                            # If we find a slice with the heart contour, set heart_contour_found to True
                            if not heart_contour_found:
                                heart_contour_found = True

        if heart_contour_found:
            # Create mask and extract pixel values for this slice
            rr, cc = polygon(np.array([p[0] for p in img.contour_points]), np.array([p[1] for p in  img.contour_points]), img.pixel_array.shape)
            mask = np.zeros_like(img.pixel_array, dtype=bool)
            mask[rr, cc] = True
            roi_pixels = img.pixel_array[mask]

            if roi_pixels.size > 0:
                # Get the rescale slope and intercept from the CT image metadata
                rescale_slope = img.RescaleSlope
                rescale_intercept = img.RescaleIntercept

                # Convert pixel values to Hounsfield Units using the formula: HU = pixel_value * rescale_slope + rescale_intercept
                hounsfield_units = roi_pixels * rescale_slope + rescale_intercept

                # Calculate the mean Hounsfield Unit value for the heart on this CT slice
                mean_hu = np.mean(hounsfield_units)

                # Display the CT image along with the heart contour and the mean Hounsfield Unit value
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                ax.imshow(img.pixel_array, cmap='gray')
                ax.set_title(f"Mean HU: {mean_hu}")
                ax.plot([p[1] for p in img.contour_points], [p[0] for p in img.contour_points], linewidth=2, color='r')
                plt.show()
            else:
                print(f"No valid pixel values found for slice {img.SOPInstanceUID}")
        else:
            print(f"No heart contour found for slice {img.SOPInstanceUID}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing slice {img.SOPInstanceUID}: {str(e)}")


(1) come up with a segmentation mask (2) fill image where mask is true. step 2 is trivial, I'd think, because you do work with numpy arrays. your question doesn't sound like you're asking how to do step 1. you said you were able to calculate "the" hounsfield unit for the heart, so I'll assume that you have a mask for the heart already. -- please clarify what precisely prevents you from achieving your goal.

Thank you for your advice. I made a mask for the heart and was able to change its Hunsfield unit.
